# Is it possible to remove/modify text in table cells depending on the content of the neighbouring cells?

Tags: javascript, extendscript, framemaker

I'm trying to use Extendscript to conditionally find and replace text within a table cell (in Adobe Framemaker). 
Is it possible to remove data from cells depending on the content of the neighbouring cells of a Framemaker table?

Below is a very basic example of the predicament I have. I have hundreds of tables that I need to edit. They contain data in rows of two as below, and are separated by a black row between each pair. The top row always has 2 variations (1 or 2). I want to know if its possible to write a script that will allow me to remove "A" from the cells that have a "2" in the neighbouring cells (immediately above) and retain "A" in all cells with a "1" immediately above. As clear as mud right?
Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm pretty much a total newbie.

1   1   2   1   1   1

A   A   A   A   A   A

1   1   1   2   1   2

A   A   A   A   A   A

Answer (score 2):

Did you post this question in the framemaker forum https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1837006 as well?
I see that it has been answered in that forum. If the answer from that forum worked for you, we can close this question with a reference.